# Adding header to retrofit call request

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am working on an Android app that is connected to a VPN.

I am sending a retrofit request to a rest api:

```
private void login_Request(){


        Log.d("ESTOY EN LOGIN REQUEST","ESTOY EN LOGIN REQUEST");
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest("HALEJANDRO","ALEJANDR0123","password","19.3509","-99.1566");

        Call <LoginRequest> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.createLoginReques(loginRequest);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginRequest>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginRequest> call, Response<LoginRequest> response) {


                Log.d("ESTOY EN LOGIN REQUEST","ESTOY EN LOGIN REQUEST rsponse "+response);


                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }

                List<Login> login = (List<Login>) response.body();

                for (Login loginResponse : login ){
                    String content = "";
                    content += "Access Token: " + loginResponse.getAccess_topken() + "\n";
                    content += "Token Type: " + loginResponse.getToken_type() + "\n";


                    textViewResult.append(content);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginRequest> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Now I need to a add a header to the request.

The header should be as follows:

```
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I have been searching for a way to add the header to the request, but I haven't a solution that could be implemented in my case.

EDIT

This is the interface:

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    @GET("posts")
    Call<List<Post>> getPosts();

    @POST("token")
    @Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    Call <LoginRequest>createLoginRequest(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
}
```

EDIT POSTMAN REQUEST

Part 1

[image]

Part 2

[image]

Part 3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can harcode any header value as follow

```
@POST("auth")
@Headers("Any value")
fun createLoginRequest(@Body credentials: Credentials): Observable<Response<User>>
```

For more info see [this link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header)

In your case, x-www-form-urlencoded request should be handled like in [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded) example:

```
public interface TaskService {  
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("tasks")
    Call<Task> createTask(@Field("title") String title);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have included your proposal at my interface, as follows:  @POST("token")
    @Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    Call <LoginRequest>createLoginRequest(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);

Comment: But I am getting an error message from the API: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://10.128.0.2:5000/token

Comment: I am checking the header and parameters using a Rest API client, like Postman, and it works with the same header and parameters

Comment: Well generally 400 occur when the payload your are sending is not the one that expect the server. What's your LoginRequest object look like?

Comment: I know, that's why I am checking the parameters keys and values with Postman, and they  work at Postman

Comment: Can you share your postman setting?  When you say "parameters keys and values" are you talking about the Json payload?

Comment: Screenshots added.

Comment: Ok. So in your case your payload is a Json, not a text. The @Body annotation will convert your POJO to it's Json representation. If you have not access to the server code, you would have to change the request. This link will help you: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded. I'll update my response too.

Comment: Now, that I have changed the code, I am getting new error messages. I need to change all the Calls then using FormUrlEncoded makes me remove the Body tag completely and also the complete request 
        Call <LoginRequest> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.createLoginReques(loginRequest);

Comment: can you help me with the needed code that should be change to incluide all parameters and header?